# jquery mobile, disable all button when loading overlay is showed

Tags: javascript, button, jquery-mobile, overlay

Actually i can call this code

```
$(":input").attr("disabled",true); //Disable all input fields
```

to disable all buttons on my page. But i don't know how good is the performance when i have a lot of button on my page.

I saw a trick that we create a loading indicator overlay, which is above all element on the page => user can not click on the buttons anymore

is there any way to reuse the loading overlay of jquery mobile to archive the above trick? I'm not good at CSS so hopefully someone can help me.

Thanks

**Edited:**

i ended up with using jquery.blockUI plugin for jQuery and it works as expected.
And i added the default div with css from jquery mobile so that i still have the loading message of jquery mobile and the behaviour that i wanted

[Working sample here](http://jsfiddle.net/peacemoon/rRKRr/3/)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

A simple way I've just found is to use a fixed background with `z-index` and `opacity`:

Add this CSS:

```
.ui-loader-background {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    top:0;
    margin: 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    display:none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index:100;
}

.ui-loading .ui-loader-background {
    display:block;
}
```

`ui-loader-background` is a custom class, but `ui-loading` is added by JQM to the `<html>` element when the loading spinner is shown.

And add this element in your body:

```
<div class="ui-loader-background"> </div>
```

example : http://jsfiddle.net/5GB6B/1/

Comment: Nice trick, but fails in Android if the loading message is shown while an input field is focused.

Comment: I finally got it done. I had to manually remove the focus for every input before showing the loading message. The background div works great preventing interaction with the page. I just commented the display:none in the css.

Comment: After clicking on the Button, Just press the Tab in Keyboard, Even though the overlay displaying, its focusing the behind all the input elements.

Comment: Just a comment - on page load add that div via js: `if (!$('.ui-loader-background').length) {
            $('body').prepend('<div class="ui-loader-background"></div>');
        }`

Answer (score 14):

In my case I use:

```
$("body").addClass('ui-disabled');
$.mobile.loading("show",{
text: "Cargando",
textVisible: true
});
```

Shows loading custom message and disable the entire page.

When you've finish your task, then you need to:

```
$.mobile.loading("hide");
$("body").removeClass('ui-disabled');
```

Hope helps you

Comment: If you operate on body with disable then loading element is disabled too. So better idea is to add and remove the class on a div and finally loading element remains enable (in the visual sense).Anyway, adding and removing 'ui-disabled' helped me :)

Answer (score 1):

I've made a small edit to the working solution provided by Xorax to move the loader background to the leftmost of the browser window as I noticed in my Chrome browser there was some area not fully covered:

```
.ui-loader-background {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    margin: 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    display:none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index:100;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Docs:

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b1/docs/api/methods.html

Show the page loading message, which is configurable via $.mobile.loadingMessage.
Example:

```
//cue the page loader           
$.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();
```

Hide the page loading message, which is configurable via $.mobile.loadingMessage.
Example:

```
//cue the page loader           
$.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I know how to hide and show the loading message. But my problem is that, when this message is showed, users can still click on the buttons on the page. I just want to know how we effectively disable all buttons when this message is showed